# Maven Spring Boot Plugin : how to run spring boot from another project

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/usage.html

I have a project, with 2 modules.

```
[Parent]  
|-pom.xml
|  [SpringBoot2App]  
|  |-pom.xml  
|  [test]  
|  |-pom.xml  (start goal here!)
```

I want to run integration tests (maven failsafe plugin) in a separate project which is another module.

Is is possible to configure the spring boot maven plugin to start/stop the child module, during the integration tests of the parent module?

I tried something like this without success

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>

            <configuration>

                <mainClass>com.SimpleServiceApplication</mainClass>
                <classesDirectory>../SpringBoot2App/target/classes</classesDirectory>
                <folders>
                     <param>../SpringBoot2App/target/test-classes</param>
                </folders>

            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Which does not work.

I also tried to add a "project" parameter after reading the source of the super class of the plugin 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/maven/AbstractRunMojo.java

```
            <configuration> 
                <mainClass>com.SimpleServiceApplication</mainClass>
                <project>${project.parent.collectedProjects[0]}</project>
            </configuration>
```

This refers to the right project, as debug shows, but does not work either.

Please don't comment on the [0], I know the [0] is not clean and is a coupling that requires direct knowledge of parent pom module ordering.

I get a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication

I added the starter-web project to the test pom.xml, same result

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to run integration tests against another module using `spring-boot-maven-plugin`, because the `start` goal doesn't seem to give you a means to resolve the application from the local repository or the Maven reactor, which is probably what you want. The `project` configuration property you've tried isn't designed to be overriden that way. Plugin executions should be configured using only the properties listed in the plugin goal [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.2.RELEASE/maven-plugin/start-mojo.html).

Instead I think you've got at least two possible approaches:

1. Use a different plugin for controlling the server; or
2. Run the server directly from the tests in code.

### Option 1

For this I think you need an approach that copies in the server artifact you want to run, together with something a bit more general for starting and stopping it, like [cargo-maven2-plugin](https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/cargo/Maven2+plugin.html) or [process-exec-maven-plugin](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/maven-process-plugin).

Just configure the `repackage` goal in the server artifact build:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <excludeDevtools>true</excludeDevtools>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then from the integration tests module, you could do something like:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-server-artifact</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>SpringBoot2App</artifactId>
                        <version>${project.version}</version>
                        <classifier>jar</classifier>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                        <destFileName>app.jar</destFileName>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>com.bazaarvoice.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>process-exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.7</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>start-server</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <name>run-server</name>
                <waitForInterrupt>false</waitForInterrupt>
                <healthcheckUrl>http://localhost:8080</healthcheckUrl>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>java</argument>
                    <argument>-jar</argument>
                    <argument>${project.build.directory}/app.jar</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>

        <execution>
            <id>stop-server</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>stop-all</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

### Option 2

Just declare a normal Maven dependency on the server artifact from the test artifact, and run the server's `@SpringBootApplication` class in a JUnit before hook or what have you, e.g.

```
private static ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

@BeforeClass
public static void setUp() {
    context = new SpringApplicationBuilder(SimpleServiceApplication.class).run();
}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDown() {
    if (context != null) {
        context.close();
    }
}
```

This may be sufficient for your needs.

Answer (score 3):

Solutions from RyanP totally fit the needs.

But, I did manage to make it work, out of luck I guess :)

1. it required re-adding dependencies in the TEST module, that are needed to run the app. (spring-boot.starter-web in this case)
2. adding the tests classes, required a very interesting syntax

So far the advantages are that I can run test on a running server, yet still mock a few services using a profile and the test-classes of the service.

Honestly, I will still try both solutions above, but just for the show, here's what I finally got working

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-mocked-app</id>
                    <configuration>

                        <arguments>
                            <argument>--server.port=${tomcat.http.port}</argument>
                        </arguments>

                        <mainClass>xxx.TestApplication</mainClass>
                        <classesDirectory>../${api-module}/target/classes</classesDirectory>

                        <folders>
                            <!-- wow! notice the weird "./" rather than the expected "../" -->
                            <folder>./${api-module}/target/test-classes</folder>
                        </folders>


                        <profiles>
                            <profile>MOCKED</profile>
                        </profiles>

                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>stop</id>

                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

And...

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- ... -->
</dependencies>
```