# Spring Boot maven plugin cant find main class, Could not exec java

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have a multi module maven spring-booot maven project. One of the child modules is a stub(a spring boot app) that I want to start and then stop **during integration tests of** ***myRealApp***.

```
Parent Pom
|   
|----myRealApp module(spring boot app)
|----stub-of-some-remote-rest-api module(This is also a spring-boot app)
```

This is how the pom file looks like in the module myRealApp. Which also has all the integration tests. Its trying to start the stub module during before integration-tests phase. But I get the error when I run maven goal in the child module directory:

```
 mvn integration-tests -X
```

> Error: Could not find or load main class io.swagger.MyStub
>
> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute 
>       goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.8.RELEASE:run 
>       (start-boot) on project: Could not exec java

I can see in debug mode that that the working directory is set correctly.

Pom of myRealApp:

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>${spring.boot.mainclass}</mainClass>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <configuration>
                        <workingDirectory>${project.parent.basedir}/module-of-my-stub/src/main/java</workingDirectory>
                        <mainClass>io.swagger.MyStub</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                    <id>start-boot</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop-boot</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-info</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>

        </plugin>
```

Maybe I am not allowed to set workingDirectory in individual executions, or give reference to an other module?

The stub is there acting like a remote rest service which my application is depending on, which I used during development since the actual remote service's test environment was not reliable and was down half of the time. So decided to also use it in Integration tests too.

Comment: Why have you configured spring-boot-maven-plugin with different executions? If you like to write integration tests it's easy to do ...Furthermore why are you using such a strange directory `/my-stub/src/main/java` ? Please follow conventions for Maven and the conventions for Spring Boot....Furthermore you should read the guides about testing spring boot apps cause there is no need to write a stub for spring boot apps...

Comment: @khmarbaise The stub is there acting like a remote rest service which my application is depending on, which I used during development since the actual remote service's test environment was not reliable and was down half the time. So why not using it also for integration tests? Why it is a strange directory? I am trying to find the  main class of the stub module from my application. I'm afraid you didn't understand my question.

Comment: @khmarbaise I updated the question

Comment: Ideally there would be a way to add the `module-of-my-stub` dependency to the classpath the `spring-boot-maven-plugin:run` goal uses.  It doesn't look like there is a direct way, though there is a [useTestClasspath](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/run-mojo.html#useTestClasspath) option.  [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50611499/1794485) also discusses an alternative approach.

Comment: @df778899 you mean I can instead put my plugin configuration in the Pom of the stub and from there by using useTestClasspath, reference to myRealApp test class?

Comment: Other way round, but it is speculation.  The thinking is that by adding a test dependency of `module-of-my-stub` to `myRealApp`, and then adding `useTestClasspath` to the existing `spring-boot-maven-plugin:run` configuration, this would make `MyStub` visible to it on the classpath.  Otherwise, the `classesDirectory`  trick in the link above should be able to point it to the `target/classes` directory under `module-of-my-stub`.

Comment: @df778899 the second option seems to be starting the stub, but its not respecting the properties files of the stub eg, cant set port or spring security password. Can I fix that?

Comment: Sounds like another directory is needed on the classpath the `spring-boot-maven-plugin:run` is using.  The other possibility looks like a `<folders>` list in the configuration - there's also an example of this in [that second link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50611499/1794485).

Comment: @Spring do you use intellij???

Comment: @df778899  if you can write an answer about explaining usage of classesDirectory I will accept your answer. It helped.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - feel free to edit/expand the answer with anything else you found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To consolidate some of the comments against the question, these basically followed the advice in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50611499/1794485).

The key was setting the `classesDirectory` against the `spring-boot-maven-plugin:run` goal to point to the `target\classes` directory under the other project.

```
  <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <mainClass>${spring.boot.mainclass}</mainClass>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>start-stub</id>
                <configuration>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>--server.port=8090</argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <mainClass>io.swagger.Stub</mainClass>
                    <classesDirectory>../my-stub/target/classes</classesDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>start</goal>
                </goals>
                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            </execution>

            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>build-info</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

`spring-boot:run` only works on the project that packages the springboot application. Best option to make this work: you'll need to use the [exec-maven-plugin:exec](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html), ensure that `async` is set to `true`. Look at https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/examples/example-exec-for-java-programs.html to see how you should configure the plugin.