# Run a spring boot app located on another project before running karate tests?

Tags: spring-boot, karate, maven-compiler-plugin

I'm trying to build some karate tests to a spring boot application. Here's the project structure :

```
co-training-backend            (parent)
   |_ co-training-rest         (maven module)
   |_ co-training-rest-karate  (maven module)
```

If i run the server and launch the karate tests everything works fine. Now i'd like to automate that by running the server from the rest-karate module.
Here's my config :

```
class CoTrainingTests {

    private static ConfigurableApplicationContext context = null;

    @BeforeAll
    public static void setUp() throws Exception {

        context = SpringApplication.run(RestBootstrap.class, new String[]{});
    }

    @Karate.Test
    Karate testAll() {
        return Karate.run().relativeTo(getClass());
    }

    @AfterAll
    public static void tearDown() throws Exception {
       if(context!=null)
           context.stop();
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
 <artifactId>co-training-rest-karate</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <junit-jupiter.version>5.6.2</junit-jupiter.version>
    <karate.version>0.9.6</karate.version>
    <maven.compiler.version>3.8.1</maven.compiler.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
            <artifactId>karate-apache</artifactId>
            <version>${karate.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
            <artifactId>karate-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>${karate.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- this is the spring boot rest project -->
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>co-training-rest</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.co.training</groupId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/java</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

If i run the tests from the command line i have this maven compiler error :

```
mvn clean test
```

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project co-training-rest-karate: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /home/salto/tutorials/co-training/co-training-backend/co-training-rest-karate/src/test/java/cotraining/CoTrainingTests.java:[3,28] package com.co.training.rest does not exist

but this class exists in the rest dependency :

```
ls /home/salto/.m2/repository/com/co/training/co-training-rest/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/co-training-rest-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

/home/salto/.m2/repository/com/co/training/co-training-rest/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/co-training-rest-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

any idea ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `integration-test` phase of the `maven` lifecycle:

1. **pre-integration-test**: start the `co-training-rest` module
2. **integration-test**: run you `karate` integration tests
3. **post-integration-test**: shut down the `co-training-rest` module and do
   any other necessary cleanup

Comment: Thx Mas. for your it points me to the solution (it's a workaround because i didn't figure out why maven can't find the dependency ). I've used maven-dependency-plugin to copy the co-training-rest sources into the karate module then i used process-exec-maven-plugin to run and stop the server (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50575478/maven-spring-boot-plugin-how-to-run-spring-boot-from-another-project) the last thing to do is to configure the surefire plugin to run only on the integration-test phase (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399240/how-do-i-get-my-maven-integration-tests-to-run).